# How to Redirect page after removing Query String

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have bunch of old website URLs that are I am trying to redirect to new destination , right now I am trying to remove query string from old URLS and then redirect to new URL with its parameters like

**Previous**: www.domain.com/ranges.php?reqinfo=some-data-info

**Required**: www.domain.com/info/ranges/some-data-info

I am trying this in .htaccess

```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^\ranges\.php\?reqinfo=(.*)$  [NC]
   RewriteRule ^info/ranges/%1? [L,R=301]
```

I have also tried one other rule but it also remove all peramaters as well

```
RewriteRule ^ranges\.php$ /info/ranges/$1? [L,R=301]
```

can someone please help.

Comment: The `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable will only have the query string part of the url, which is the part after `?`, not the filename. Not sure if it includes the `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ranges.php` is part of your REQUEST_URI hence you cannot match in using `QUERY_STRING` condition. Use it as:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^reqinfo=([^&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ranges\.php$ /info/ranges/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```